# ¿Cómo colocar imagen en archivo html desde mi carpeta con c#?

Tags: c#, html, visual-studio, imagen

Buen día a todos.

Hago esta consulta acá porque al final no he logrado colocar una imagen que tengo en mi carpeta a un archivo html mediante c#

```
String codigo =
 + "< img src = "+ '"' +ruta+"imagen"+ ".png " + '"'+ "> "  ;
```

Este es un fragmento de mi archivo que concateno, la ruta que le llega es
C:/Users/ang_e/Documents/.

Obviamente esto no funciona así porque no me muestra la imagen que tengo en esa localización y lo único que hace es mostrarme el fragmento de código que esta escrito en el código html que adjunto.

```
< img src = "C:/Users/ang_e/Documents/imagen.png">
```

Si alguien me puede ayudar a como especificar mejor la ruta para generar el html con la imagen añadida se lo agradecería bastante.

Estoy programando en c# visual studio. Cabe mencionar que la imagen la creo desde c# utilizando un archivo .dot.

Comment: estas tratando de incrustar un string en tu html? eso es el problema?

Comment: No, mas bien hacer la inserción de una imagen en mi archivo html que tengo en la carpeta Documentos desde mi proyecto c#. La forma en que lo he planteado en mi pregunta no funciona.

Comment: Pero la imagen tiene que estar dentro de tu proyecto.. en la carpeta que sea que guardas las imagenes. No se puede incrustar en un HTML, siempre se lee del disco...

Comment: Entiendo, eso debe ser. Debo guardar la imagen en una carpeta de imagenes de mi proyecto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si las imágenes no están en otra carpeta no hay problema con la ubicación. Es mas bien la forma en que el html está escrito.

```
String codigo =
 + "< img src = " + '"' + "grafo" + 1 + ".png" + '"' + "/>\n"
```

El código anterior está separado por el signo menor que, de la palabra img, eso afecta la forma en que la computadora entiende la sintaxis.

La solución:

```
+ "<img src = " + '"' + "grafo" + i + ".png" + '"' + "/>\n"
```

Juntar ese signo (<) con la palabra (img). Con eso se debería mostrar la imagen en la página html.

Answer (score 0):

Lo correcto en Asp.net es que guardes tus imagenes dentro del mismo proyecto.

Te recomiendo crear una carpeta en la raiz de tu proyecto, algo como "Imagenes" y ahí meter todo lo que necesitas utilizar de imagenes.

Y lo puedes obtener así:

```
String rutaWeb = Server.MapPath(@"~/Imagenes/imagen.png");
```

Eso te va a regresar no una ruta como si estubieras en tu computadora si no una ruta web que es lo que necesita el servidor web.

Revisa la variables rutaWeb y verás que no te regresa un directorio como "C:/..." si no algo mas como "localhost/..." o tu IP local.